# Run time check error 2

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

Alright sorry for asking another one of these questions. I have looked around staackoverflow for an answer. I am getting the error stack around variable nums.Does that mean that I type some extra code near the variable nums or something? I have tried figuring it out but I can't find it. I am a noob at coding so sorry. Here is my code and I think the problem lies with my

```
cout << "The numbers on file are:\n " << nums, size;
```

and my calling of the read_data above main but I cannot find the problem. Thanks!

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void read_data(int nums[], int size);

int main()
{
const int size = 24;
ifstream dataIn;
int nums[size];

   read_data(nums,size);

   cout << "The numbers on file are:\n " << nums, size;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void read_data(int nums[], int size)
{
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("walrus.txt");

    if( dataIn.fail() )
            {
                    cout << "File does not exist." << endl;
                    exit(1);
            } 

    int count;
    for ( count = 0; count < size; count++ )
    {
             dataIn >> nums[size];
    }

    dataIn.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the run-time issue -

```
dataIn >> nums[size];
```

Trying to access array indexes out of bounds is undefined behavior. Valid array indexes of size **N** is **0** to **N-1**.

Comment: @user3267868  Additionally... stack around variable"nums"?? Maybe you mean that nums is on the stack memory.

Comment: It is not a issue in this case even if `nums` is on stack. Life time of `nums` is until `main` returns.

Comment: I know, I can't wrap my head around his question " stack around variable"nums""